# How to serialize a c# object with polymorphism to a soapmessage with overriden soapattributes, similar to XmlAttributeOverrides?

Tags: c#, serialization, soap

I have a dynamically created type, so I can't change it's implementation. I can't apply solutions like

```
[SoapInclude()]
```

Imagine if I had such classes:

```
public class BaseClass{}
public class DerivedClass:BaseClass{}
public class AnotherDerivedClass:BaseClass{}

public class RequestClass
{
    public BaseClass item{get;set;}
}
```

If we try to just simply serialize we get the exception that *DerivedClass was not found*, so we have to override the xmlattributes.
I have managed to override my Type and serialize it with `XmlAttributeOverrides` like so:

```
var requestObject = new RequestClass() {item = new DerivedClass()};
XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
XmlElementAttribute attr = new XmlElementAttribute
{
    ElementName = "DerivedClass",
    Type = typeof(DerivedClass)
};
attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);
XmlAttributeOverrides attoverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
attoverrides.Add(typeof(RequestClass), "item", attrs);
XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RequestClass), attoverrides);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
sr.Serialize(writer, requestObject);
var xml = writer.ToString();
```

Now the above works, but what I want is to serialize my object as a soap-message.  I have found similar classes to those above Like `SoapAttributeOverrides` and I've tried to override it with those classes and it doesn't seem to work. I've tried it like :

```
var requestObject = new RequestClass(){item = new DerivedClass()};
SoapAttributeOverrides ovr = new SoapAttributeOverrides();
SoapAttributes soapAtts = new SoapAttributes();
SoapElementAttribute element = new SoapElementAttribute();
element.ElementName = "DerivedClass";
ovr.Add(typeof(RequestClass), "item", soapAtts);
var sr = new XmlSerializer(new SoapReflectionImporter(ovr).ImportTypeMapping(typeof(RequestClass)));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
sr.Serialize(writer, requestObject);
var xml = writer.ToString();
writer.Close();
```

I again get the exception *DerivedClass was not found*. How can I give the `SoapElementAttribute` a type similar to `XmlElementAttribute.Type` so that serialization can be made to support polymorphism for `BaseClass` via overrides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP-encoded XML serialization in .Net supports polymorphism via an [included type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.soapincludeattribute?view=netframework-4.8) mechanism.  In order to add included types to a `SoapReflectionImporter` in runtime, use either:

- [`SoapReflectionImporter.IncludeType(Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.soapreflectionimporter.includetype?view=netcore-2.2#System_Xml_Serialization_SoapReflectionImporter_IncludeType_System_Type_)
- [`SoapReflectionImporter.IncludeTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.soapreflectionimporter.includetypes?view=netcore-2.2#System_Xml_Serialization_SoapReflectionImporter_IncludeTypes_System_Reflection_ICustomAttributeProvider_).

Thus you can manufacture your `XmlSerializer` as follows:

```
public static XmlSerializer RequestClassSerializer { get; } 
    = CreateSoapSerializerWithBaseClassIncludedTypes(typeof(RequestClass), typeof(DerivedClass), typeof(AnotherDerivedClass));

static XmlSerializer CreateSoapSerializerWithBaseClassIncludedTypes(Type rootType, params Type [] includedTypes)
{
    var importer = new SoapReflectionImporter();
    foreach (var type in includedTypes)
        importer.IncludeType(type);
    return new XmlSerializer(importer.ImportTypeMapping(rootType));
}
```

Then introduce the following extension method:

```
public static partial class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static string GetSoapXml<T>(this T obj, XName wrapperName, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement(wrapperName.LocalName, wrapperName.NamespaceName);
                (serializer ?? GetDefaultSoapSerializer(obj.GetType())).Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    static readonly Dictionary<Type, XmlSerializer> cache = new Dictionary<Type, XmlSerializer>();

    public static XmlSerializer GetDefaultSoapSerializer(Type type)
    {
        lock(cache)
        {
            if (cache.TryGetValue(type, out var serializer))
                return serializer;
            return cache[type] = new XmlSerializer(new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(type));
        }
    }
}
```

And you will be able to serialize your `requestObject` as follows:

```
var requestObject = new RequestClass(){item = new DerivedClass()};

var xml = requestObject.GetSoapXml("wrapper", RequestClassSerializer);
```

Notes:

- To avoid a severe memory leak you should statically cache any `XmlSerializer` not created with the `XmlSerializer(Type)` or `XmlSerializer(Type, String)` constructors.  For why, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8#dynamically-generated-assemblies) and also *[Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182)*.

  If you are dynamically generating families of types you may need to cache their serializers in a static dictionary protected by `lock` statements.
- As explained in *[Extension method to serialize generic objects as a SOAP formatted stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6401075/3744182)* and *[InvalidOperationException while SOAP serialization of complex type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011512/3744182)* you need to manually write an envelope or other wrapper element before serializing directly to XML using a SOAP XML serializer.

  If for some reason you just want the SOAP XML body as a series of XML fragments, you can do:

  ```
  public static string GetSoapBodyXml<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
  {
      using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
      {
          var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment }; // For cosmetic purposes.
          using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
          {
              xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace(""); // Hack to prevent an error about WriteStartDocument getting called for ConformanceLevel.Fragment
              (serializer ?? GetDefaultSoapSerializer(obj.GetType())).Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
          }
          return textWriter.ToString();
      }
  }
  ```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cC3RDZ).

Comment: Yeah, i did something similar. I know how the soap-format is supposed to look in my case. So i just did the thing that i can do statically and the rest well that was for me to figure out. Still thanks for the effort. I will mark your answer as correct, cause apparently there is no way around and the c# object itself i serialized with xmlattributesoverrides and inserted it into the soap-body.